# How to know whether the off diagonal entries are positive or negative? What is the relationship between off diagonal entries and covariance?

Tags: multivariate-polynomial

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqkAa.png)

According to what I learned, off diagonal entries are Cov(x,y) and Cov(y,x).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Roughly speaking, Cov$(x,y)$ is positive iff $x$ being greater than the $x$-mean means $y$ is likely to be greater than the $y$-mean. In other words, a positive relationship. Thus, you should expect Cov$(x,y)$ to be positive based on the graph.